# Sublime Text plugin with live preview for LaTeX

Tags: windows, latex, sublime-text

I am looking for a Sublime Text plugin that gives a live preview when editing a LaTeX file. It should work on Windows.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.